# How can I fix a error of compile on linux

Tags: linux, compilation, makefile

I'm using the cross compiler (`arm-none-linux-gnueabi`) and I wanna build a `libs3-2.0 source`, but I get the following error when I try to compile.

```
libs3-2.0$ sudo make
make: *** No rule to make target `libxml/parser.h', needed by `build/obj/simplexml.do'.  Stop.
```

What can I do to solve this issue? Below is the (GNU) Makefile.

```
working directory: /home/usrname/prj/app/framework/camera/cdma_manage/<br>
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

LIBS3_VER_MAJOR ?= 2
LIBS3_VER_MINOR ?= 0
LIBS3_VER := $(LIBS3_VER_MAJOR).$(LIBS3_VER_MINOR)

ifdef VERBOSE
    VERBOSE = true
    VERBOSE_ECHO = @ echo
    VERBOSE_SHOW =
    QUIET_ECHO = @ echo > /dev/null
else
    VERBOSE = false
    VERBOSE_ECHO = @ echo > /dev/null
    VERBOSE_SHOW = @
    QUIET_ECHO = @ echo
endif

ifndef BUILD
    ifdef DEBUG
        BUILD := build-debug
    else
        BUILD := build
    endif
endif

ifndef DESTDIR
    DESTDIR := /usr
endif

ifndef CURL_LIBS
    CURL_LIBS := $(shell curl-config --libs)
endif

ifndef CURL_CFLAGS
    CURL_CFLAGS := $(shell curl-config --cflags)
endif

    ifndef LIBXML2_LIBS
        LIBXML2_LIBS := $(shell xml2-config --libs)
    endif

    ifndef LIBXML2_CFLAGS
        LIBXML2_CFLAGS := $(shell xml2-config --cflags)
    endif

    ifndef LIBXML2_LIBS
        LIBXML2_LIBS := -L../libxml2-2.7.2/.libs -lxml2 -lm
    endif

    ifndef LIBXML2_CFLAGS
        LIBXML2_CFLAGS := -I/home/usrname/prj/app/framework/camera/cdma_manage/libxml2-2.7.2/include
    endif

    ifndef CFLAGS
        ifdef DEBUG
            CFLAGS := -g
        else
            CFLAGS := -O3
        endif
    endif

CFLAGS += -Wall -Werror -Wshadow -Wextra -Iinc \
        $(CURL_CFLAGS) $(LIBXML2_CFLAGS) \
        -DLIBS3_VER_MAJOR=\"$(LIBS3_VER_MAJOR)\" \
        -DLIBS3_VER_MINOR=\"$(LIBS3_VER_MINOR)\" \
        -DLIBS3_VER=\"$(LIBS3_VER)\" \
        -D__STRICT_ANSI__ \
        -D_ISOC99_SOURCE \
        -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L

LDFLAGS = $(CURL_LIBS) $(LIBXML2_LIBS) -lpthread

.PHONY: all
all: exported test

.PHONY: exported
exported: libs3 s3 headers

.PHONY: install
install: exported
        $(QUIET_ECHO) $(DESTDIR)/bin/s3: Installing executable
        $(VERBOSE_SHOW) install -Dps -m u+rwx,go+rx $(BUILD)/bin/s3 \
        $(DESTDIR)/bin/s3
        $(QUIET_ECHO) \
        $(DESTDIR)/lib/libs3.so.$(LIBS3_VER): Installing shared library
        $(VERBOSE_SHOW) install -Dps -m u+rw,go+r \
        $(BUILD)/lib/libs3.so.$(LIBS3_VER_MAJOR) \
        $(DESTDIR)/lib/libs3.so.$(LIBS3_VER)
        $(QUIET_ECHO) \
        $(DESTDIR)/lib/libs3.so.$(LIBS3_VER_MAJOR): Linking shared library
        $(VERBOSE_SHOW) ln -sf libs3.so.$(LIBS3_VER) \
        $(DESTDIR)/lib/libs3.so.$(LIBS3_VER_MAJOR)
        $(QUIET_ECHO) $(DESTDIR)/lib/libs3.so: Linking shared library
        $(VERBOSE_SHOW) ln -sf libs3.so.$(LIBS3_VER_MAJOR) $(DESTDIR)/lib/libs3.so
        $(QUIET_ECHO) $(DESTDIR)/lib/libs3.a: Installing static library
        $(VERBOSE_SHOW) install -Dp -m u+rw,go+r $(BUILD)/lib/libs3.a \
        $(DESTDIR)/lib/libs3.a
        $(QUIET_ECHO) $(DESTDIR)/include/libs3.h: Installing header
        $(VERBOSE_SHOW) install -Dp -m u+rw,go+r $(BUILD)/include/libs3.h \
        $(DESTDIR)/include/libs3.h

.PHONY: uninstall
uninstall:
        $(QUIET_ECHO) Installed files: Uninstalling
        $(VERBOSE_SHOW) \
        rm -f $(DESTDIR)/bin/s3 \
        $(DESTDIR)/include/libs3.h \
        $(DESTDIR)/lib/libs3.a \
        $(DESTDIR)/lib/libs3.so \
        $(DESTDIR)/lib/libs3.so.$(LIBS3_VER_MAJOR) \
        $(DESTDIR)/lib/libs3.so.$(LIBS3_VER)

$(BUILD)/obj/%.o: src/%.c
        $(QUIET_ECHO) $@: Compiling object
        @ mkdir -p $(dir $(BUILD)/dep/$<)
        @ /opt/armv7/codesourcery/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc $(CFLAGS) -M -MG -MQ $@ -DCOMPILINGDEPENDENCIES \
        -o $(BUILD)/dep/$(<:%.c=%.d) -c $<
        @ mkdir -p $(dir $@)
        $(VERBOSE_SHOW) /opt/armv7/codesourcery/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(BUILD)/obj/%.do: src/%.c
        $(QUIET_ECHO) $@: Compiling dynamic object
        @ mkdir -p $(dir $(BUILD)/dep/$<)
        @ /opt/armv7/codesourcery/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc $(CFLAGS) -M -MG -MQ $@ -DCOMPILINGDEPENDENCIES \
        -o $(BUILD)/dep/$(<:%.c=%.dd) -c $<
        @ mkdir -p $(dir $@)
        $(VERBOSE_SHOW) /opt/armv7/codesourcery/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc $(CFLAGS) -fpic -fPIC -o $@ -c $< 

LIBS3_SHARED = $(BUILD)/lib/libs3.so.$(LIBS3_VER_MAJOR)
LIBS3_STATIC = $(BUILD)/lib/libs3.a

.PHONY: libs3
libs3: $(LIBS3_SHARED) $(LIBS3_STATIC)

LIBS3_SOURCES := acl.c bucket.c error_parser.c general.c \
        object.c request.c request_context.c \
        response_headers_handler.c service_access_logging.c \
        service.c simplexml.c util.c

$(LIBS3_SHARED): $(LIBS3_SOURCES:%.c=$(BUILD)/obj/%.do)
        $(QUIET_ECHO) $@: Building shared library
        @ mkdir -p $(dir $@)
        $(VERBOSE_SHOW) /opt/armv7/codesourcery/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libs3.so.$(LIBS3_VER_MAJOR) \
        -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

$(LIBS3_STATIC): $(LIBS3_SOURCES:%.c=$(BUILD)/obj/%.o)
        $(QUIET_ECHO) $@: Building static library
        @ mkdir -p $(dir $@)
        $(VERBOSE_SHOW) $(AR) cr $@ $^

... abbriviated.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: what command did you type

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that libxml/parser.h isn't found by make, but it's needed to build something else.  Have you checked that this file is in the include paths?

Comment: yes i did. i confirmed parser.h in target directory. i suspect LIBXML2_CFLAGS doesn't work on my project. but still i don't know which line is wrong.

Comment: @user2621353, you say in the target directory, but is that directory in the include path?  Target directory and include directory are two different things, and the target directory is rarely an include directory.

Comment: sorry, target directory means include path directory.

Comment: @user2621353 last thing I can suggest is using `make -d` to see what make is trying to do with each file.  Wish I could have helped more.

Comment: i have tried make -d. but i could't find a path of directory(/home/usrname/prj/app/framework/camera/cdma_manage/libxml2). i certainly set a LIBXML2_CFLAGS. what do i miss?

Answer (score 0):

```
ifndef LIBXML2_CFLAGS
        LIBXML2_CFLAGS := -I/home/usrname/prj/app/framework/camera/cdma_manage/libxml2-2.7.2/include
endif
```

should added before

```
ifndef LIBXML2_CFLAGS
        LIBXML2_CFLAGS := $(shell xml2-config --cflags)
endif
```